# Using ranger in windows through cygwin to open files correctly(rifle.py)

Tags: windows, path, cygwin, filepath, file-manager

If you installed Cygwin in windows, and also ranger inside it, then probably you can't open files via ranger, because paths in Cygwin is different with paths in windows.

In Cygwin paths are like: `/cygdrive/c/go/to/path` but in windows: `c:/go/to/path` and for this difference you can't open your files inside ranger(installed in Cygwin).

Now **how can we open our files correctly in windows using ranger**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a trick that I'm using for solving this problem.

1. **Open your rifle file**

*If you don't know where is it, you need to create the default one by running ranger with this command:* `ranger --copy-config all` *and it will copy the default config files on your home directory(home/.config/ranger/CONFIG_FILES)*

2. **Edit commands**(ex: text editor)

Here is the main section, find the line with this content:

`mime ^text,  label editor = ${VISUAL:-$EDITOR} -- "$@"`

the `"$@"` refers to the path of the selected file, but it's wrong, you need to change it like this:

`` mime ^text,  label editor = runemacs.exe -- `sed 's%/cygdrive/e/%e:/%g' <<< "$@"` ``

- As you can see, I changed the `${VISUAL:-$EDITOR}` variable to my own program(runemacs.exe)
- `` `commands` `` is command substitute(in Linux) and will print the output of its commands for us
- `<<<` is the here doc(again it's a Linux feature)
- `sed` is a command for search/replace
- `sed 's%/cygdrive/e/%e:/%g'` means that search[*using `s` command*] for `/cygdrive/e/`[you can change this path to your own], and replace it with `e:/`, and also the `g` means globally search and replace it.

3. **Done**