# How to open a folder in Ranger with explorer.exe (Cygwin)

Tags: python, windows, cygwin, file-manager

**In windows** when you use **ranger**(**by using cygwin**), how can you open folders with explorer.exe?
I mean when you press `r` on a folder, it will ask you to open-width a command, but if you write `explorer.exe "$1"` **it doesn't open it**, how can we do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because **the paths in windows and Linux are different**, you can't open folders selected in ranger with explorer.exe.

`/cygwin/c/backup` isn't equal to `c:\backup`, and won't work with explorer.exe.

So we have to change the path, to the one that windows like it.

Open your `rifle.py` file, if you don't know where is it and how to create it see this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68578770/using-ranger-in-windows-through-cygwin-to-open-files-correctlyrifle-py)

Now at the end of that file, you can add this line:

```
directory, else = explorer.exe "$(echo "$1" | cat | sed -r 's~/cygdrive/(.)/(.*)~ \1\:/\2 ~g' | cat | sed 's~/~\\~g' | sed -r 's~^ (.*)~\1~g')"
```

It's a bunch of `sed` commands that convert the Linux(Cygwin) path model to windows like path. and the open that path with explorer.exe(you can change explorer.exe with any other program you like).